# How to fetch Specific row from google-sheet by using Google-sheet-apis(Node.js)?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I used google-apis SDK for my development. I can able to get values from sheet by using `sheets.spreadsheets.values.get` method. But it returns entire values from that sheet. I need to filter something like querying.

Here what I actually trying,

[Sample Sheet Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcBDE.png)

Assume the above data as a spreadsheet, Here `sheets.spreadsheets.values.get` this returns whole values from that sheet. But I try to do fetch first row by `Email=surya@aaa.com`

Comment: please edit your question and include your code and show us what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) allows (and requires) you to specify a range

A sample value for `range` - for getting row 5 of Sheet1 would be `Sheet1!A5:Z5`

**UPDATE**

If you do not know which row you want to retrieve, but want to incorporate a query request, such as in the Google Sheets UI:

**It is not possible with Google Sheets API.**

But there is a workaround:

**Use a Google [Visualization API query](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#setting-the-query-from-javascript).**

Workflow:

- Publish your spreadsheet as "Anyone with the link can view"
- Create the URL by

  - taking the basic URL of your spreadsheet `https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXXXXX`
  - add to the URL `/gviz/tq?tq=`
  - create you query such as in Sheets UI and URL encode it
  - Add the URL encoded query to your URL
- Perform a simple fetch request with the resulting URL

**Sample:**

If your query is `select A`,

- the URL would be `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXXXX/gviz/tq?tq=select%20A`
- and the response of a GET request would be:

```
google.visualization.Query.setResponse({"version":"0.6","reqId":"0","status":"ok","sig":"1023816999","table":{"cols":[{"id":"A","label":"","type":"number","pattern":"General"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":1.0,"f":"1"}]},{"c":[{"v":4.0,"f":"4"}]}],"parsedNumHeaders":0}});
```

You can access the nested JSON structure as desired and of course you can formulate your query as desired.

Comment: Your correct, but I want to filter it like querying with a sheet value. Assume that column named Email Id, I want to fetch a specific row with some of the email ids.

Comment: You mean, you want to retrieve a named range?

Comment: No, I want a single row with the input of some values in the sheet, Here i using `Sheet1` as range params.

Comment: How would you formulate your query in the Sheets UI?

Comment: Why this is not possible with Google Sheets API? Any documentation?

Comment: Have a look at the [reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest) and you'll see that there is no method that accepts queries. Hence the workaround with Visulaization API. Alternatively you can retrieve all the data and implement a query function programmatically.

Comment: Ok, I agree with this. How to fetch multiple sheet data from this way like `sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchGet`.

Comment: The documentaiton provides a [sample](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet#examples) of how to implement it in node.js or another language of your choice.

Comment: Sorry, I know to use that method in Sheet API. We can pass multiple ranges to fetch data. But I want to know that, Is there is the same `batchGet` in Visualization API?

Comment: You can make yourself some kind of batch request by including all ranges of interest into a query request.

Comment: How to set a range in this visualization API?

Comment: You do not set a range there, you form a query request in such a way that it returns you your range of interest. If this is not what you want, I am afraid that you won't get around retrieving all data with Sheets API and performing the query subsequently manually programmatically.

Comment: Here I cannot query `Sheet2`, it always returns values from `Sheet1`

Comment: You can query by specifying the sheet in the query URL: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXXXXXXXX/gviz/tq?sheet=sheet2&tq=select%20A`